# Getting java components' value on the basis of their variable name

Tags: java, components

I want to get value from 20 java components 10 are jtextfields and 10 are jcombobox with their variable names not by setName().

These components are placed in row format means jtextfield1 then cmbbox1 and then jtextfield2 then cmbbox2 and so on.
now i want to loop through these components and get there value one by one exactly in the same way they are placed as value of jtextfield1 then value of cmbbox1 and then so on.

I tried my best to find answer but all in vein. Waiting for your great responses.

Comment: Don't try to reflectively get components. Place them into an array instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to preserve insertion order you can use ArrayList.

You can do something like following -

```
    List<JComponent> jComponentList = new ArrayList<>();
    //add components
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        textField.setName("textField" + i);
        comboBox.setName("comboBox" + i);
        jComponentList.add(textField);
        jComponentList.add(comboBox);
    }
    //iterate to get values
    for(JComponent component : jComponentList) {
        if(component instanceof JTextField) {
            System.out.println("textField Name is " + component.getName());
        }
        else if(component instanceof JComboBox) {
            System.out.println("jcomboBox Name is " + component.getName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Aniket for prompt response! but the issue is that components are already added and are not given names but variable names,  and i must have to get them by their variable name so i don't have to loop through all other components as well. Means to say access components with their variable names in a loop. Let me edit my question.

Comment: If by variable name you mean the name of references pointing to the actual objects than than is not good programming. Please provide code you have written. No one can help you merely by reading the question.